# Make footer move up when content appears at the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have bottom fixed footer and content that appears at the bottom too, but I want to make my footer go up when that content is loaded (and kinda stick it to the top of the content). How do I do that?

For styling I'm using SASS

```
<footer>
    <div className="social-icons">
        <div className="icon">
            <a href="http://fb.me">
                <i className="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div className="icon">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/">
                <i className="fab fa-twitter"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div className="icon">
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                <i className="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div className="icon">
            <a href="https://plus.google.com/discover">
                <i className="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
</footer>
```

sass:

```
footer
    position: fixed
    z-index: 10
    width: 100vw
    bottom: 0
    display: flex
    justify-content: space-between
    box-sizing: border-box
    flex-wrap: nowrap
    padding: 0 6.25vw  2.6042vw 6.35vw
```

The content which has to be loaded at the bottom and move the footer up:

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

sass

```
.content 
    position: absolute
    bottom: 0
    z-index: 30
    height: 6.25vw
    width: 100%
    background-color: $white
```

[image: I want footer to ALWAYS stick to the bottom except when content moves it up]

Comment: Your CSS is missing braces.

Comment: I wonder how this code works, without braces :o

Comment: sorry, forgot to say that i'm using sass

Comment: i'm a bit confused to what you are trying to do. what to you want to happen with your footer ? go up ? like to the top of the page ? or change the z-index ?

Comment: @לבני מלכה sAss does not use braces, sCss does

Comment: @Dirk I want it to go up as the content is loaded at the bottom, and kinda stick to the top of that content until it disappears

Comment: like an animation I presume??

Comment: @Dark_thunder it doesn't necessarily need to be animated. The only problem is I can't figure out how can I move up and stick my footer to content that appears at the bottom (if it does). That is when there is no content at the bottom - the footer is bottom fixed, when there is some content - the footer is right above the content which is fixed to the bottom

Comment: take a look at position [`sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky). Maybe it will help you.

Comment: providing some visual aid would be grate, for explaining what you want it to look like exactly, with content and without content. Some graphic may be

Comment: @Sanira added pics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this is what you've looking for. Try changing the height of the `.content`, the footer will always stick to the top of the content part, if there is no content in the `.content` part, the footer will stick to the bottom of the page.

```css
body{
  width: 100vw;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.upper-body{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
.footer-content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100vw;
    bottom: 0;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    background-color: yellow;
}
footer{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100vw;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    padding: 0 6.25vw  2.6042vw 6.35vw;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.content{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 6.25vw;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
    <div class="upper-body">
    </div>
    <div class="footer-content">
        <footer>
            <div className="social-icons">
                <div className="icon">
                    <a href="http://fb.me">
                        <i className="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div className="icon">
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/">
                        <i className="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div className="icon">
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                        <i className="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div className="icon">
                    <a href="https://plus.google.com/discover">
                        <i className="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
        </footer>
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: awesome, this solves my problem. thanks a lot for help!